# What is the sense of "Only God judge me"

Tags: meaning, subjunctive-mood

There is a wall near my house where this phrase has recently been graffitied -

***Only God judge me***

My reaction to this (!) has been to realise that most similarly-constructed phrases I can think of use the indicative mood:

> Only my dog *loves* me;
>
> Only his partner *tells* him what to do;
>
> Only swimming *relaxes* me;
>
> Only a fool *worries* about the niceties of English usage.

Clearly, the graffiti is not using the indicative mood. My research suggests that it's using the [jussive (mandative,declarative) mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive).  If this is the case, I'm wondering whether both of the following can be understood with equal validity, or whether, one of them only is the usual meaning:

> 1) (the author believes that) Only God ***has the authority/ability*** to judge him/her (i.e. Only God ***can*** judge)
>
> 2) (the author permits that) Only God ***may*** judge him/her

Comment: Most likely there's just a missing 'can'

Comment: Clearly 2 for me. Absolutely anyone *can* judge you. And indeed absolutely everyone *will*, especially if you go spraying on walls.

Comment: It's graffiti!!  The fact that you can make sense of it at all is notable.

Comment: Yes! Defiant rather than fatalistic...

Answer (score 3):

> Clearly, the graffiti is not using the indicative mood.

It is worth noting that graffiti is not a medium well known for its sterling grammar. The expected *meaning* of the phrase ("you people shouldn't judge me") suggests the indicative mood wasn't intended but it may mean something like "only God [really] judge[s] me [and your opinions aren't important]".

> My research suggests that it's using the jussive (mandative, declarative) mood.

Nah, there's not a main verb that would require it. It could be a *hortative* subjunctive, equivalent to "[Let] only God judge me," but in English that's usually expressed/understood as an imperative and this is an awkward way to say it.

> Most likely there's just a missing 'can'.

Yup. That's much more likely.